# Find slope by linear regression of 2 matrices (R)

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression

I have 2 matrices. One contains the quantities a client bought of products. The matrix looks like this quantitymatrix:

[image]

the other one contains unitprices at which a client bought the products. The matrix looks like this pricematrix:

[image]

How can I run a linear regression with the matrices so that I obtain the slope for each product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
quantity <-  matrix(c(4,2,6, 9,4,3, 1,1,2, 3,1,5), 3, 4)
price <-  matrix(c(1,0.5,8, 4.2,1.2,2, 2,5,2, 1,2.5,1), 3, 4)
```

First, you have to transform your two matrices into a single data frame. (Although you can avoid that if you want, but I think it makes it much more straightforward if you do so):

```
df <-  data.frame(quantity = as.numeric(quantity), 
                    price = as.numeric(price), 
                    product = rep(1:4, each = 3), ID = 1:3)
```

Then, run the linear models by groups:

```
lms <-  by(df, df$product, FUN = function(x) lm(price~quantity, data = x))
```

And get the slopes:

```
slopes <- sapply(lms, coef)[2,]
```

If however, you want to keep the orignial matrices as they are, you can run a simple loop:

```
slopes <- numeric(dim(price)[2])
for (i in 1:dim(price)[2]) {
  model <- lm(price[,i]~quantity[,i])
  slopes[i] <- coef(model)[2]
}
```

NB: this solution assumes that the two matrices have identical dimensions.

And if you want to avoid loops, the following solution may be faster:

```
f <-  function(x,y) coef(lm(y~x))[2]
l <- function(m) lapply(seq_len(ncol(m)), function(i) m[,i])

mapply(f, l(quantity), l(price))
```

Comment: Both matrices are actually of size 63657x254 so transforming them into a single dataframe returns the error: cannot allocate vector of size 123.4 Mb. Could you maybe show the solution in order to calculate the slope based on the 2 matrices separately?

Comment: OK - that wasn't clear from the question. I edited my answer to keep the original matrices.